# PS3 Media Server on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ps3-media-server

I'm very excited to have installed PS3MS on Ubuntu Server following these guides

```
 http://irrationale.com/2010/06/30/ps3-media-server-on-ubuntu-10-04/
```

But when I play WMV files, I receive this error "The data type is not supported. (800288C0)"

```
thumbnails = true
thumbnail_seek_pos = 300
mencoder_ass = true
folders = /srv/Shared
hide_videosettings = true
hide_enginenames = true
uuid = 9c5ca47f-421f-4e28-a397-325defa20f40



engines = mencoder,avsmencoder,tsmuxer,ffmpegaudio,mplayeraudio,tsmuxeraudio,vlcvideo,mencoderwebvideo,mplayervideodump,mplayerwebaudio,vlcaudio,ffmpegdvrmsremux
autoloadsrt = true
avisynth_convertfps = true
avisynth_script = #AviSynth script is now fully customisable !\u0001#You must use the following variables (\"clip\" being the avisynth variable of the movie):\u0001#<movie>: insert the complete DirectShowSource instruction [ clip=DirectShowSource(movie, convertfps) ]\u0001#<sub>: insert the complete TextSub\/VobSub instruction if there's any detected srt\/sub\/idx\/ass subtitle file\u0001#<moviefilename>: variable of the movie filename, if you want to do all this by yourself\u0001#Be careful, the custom script MUST return the clip object\u0001<movie>\u0001<sub>\u0001return clip
transcode_block_multiple_connections = false
tsmuxer_forcefps = true
tsmuxer_preremux_pcm = false
tsmuxer_preremux_ac3 = false
audiochannels = 6
audiobitrate = 448
maximumbitrate = 110
skiploopfilter = false
enable_archive_browsing = false
mencoder_fontconfig = false
mencoder_font =
mencoder_forcefps = false
mencoder_usepcm = false
mencoder_intelligent_sync = true
mencoder_decode =
mencoder_encode = keyint=5:vqscale=1:vqmin=2
mencoder_vobsub_subtitle_quality = 3
mencoder_overscan_compensation_width = 0
mencoder_overscan_compensation_height = 0
mencoder_nooutofsync = true
mencoder_audiolangs = fre,jpn,ger,eng
mencoder_sublangs = fre,eng
mencoder_audiosublangs =
mencoder_subfribidi = false
mencoder_ass_scale = 1.0
mencoder_ass_margin = 10
mencoder_ass_outline = 1
mencoder_ass_shadow = 1
mencoder_noass_scale = 3
mencoder_noass_subpos = 2
mencoder_noass_blur = 1
mencoder_noass_outline = 1
mencoder_subcp = cp1252
mencoder_disablesubs = false
mencoder_yadif = false
mencoder_scaler = false
mencoder_scalex = 0
mencoder_scaley = 0
ffmpeg = -g 1 -qscale 1 -qmin 2
```

Is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to go into the "#Transcoded#" Folder?

Comment: Yes, for each video there are three entries in #Transcoded# folder, none of which work

Answer (score 1):

I had problems until I used this guide: http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13046

Ubuntu users can install PS3 Media Server (and keep it up to date) automatically with these simple commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.